# read header cookie with Angularjs and Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, cordova, cookies

I have a problem with my application Cordova / Angularjs.

I can log me in my api that returns me a cookie :
Set-Cookie:token=654vze45ze566ze5;

But I can not recover those values ​​and return them when I do a "GET".

I tried with ngCookies but apparently cookies do not work on phonegap, How can I read and retrieve the header Set-Cookie ?